# Is a POCO not supposed to have a base class?

Tags: c#, poco

I have 3 different types of data: images, videos, and audio clips. Each one has an associated GPS point, so I have a base class as such:

```
public abstract class Data {
    public Latitude { get; set; }
    public Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

This is so I can plot everything on a map without worrying about what kind of data it is. However, I've been reading that POCO is not supposed be derived from anything except the base `object` class in C#. Is this true?

Comment: While not answering your question, I urge you to reconsider the base-class name "Data".  That really says nothing.  Every class is data, in a very real sense.   I suggest "Location" as a slightly more descriptive name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, many POCO objects have base classes.There is no rule saying they can't have or should have base classes. If it makes sense in your application then do it.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with inheritance for plain old clr objects. In fact, inheritance is a driving factor as to why I like to use POCO objects instead things like Datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that? How would you build an object hierarchy if you were not allowed to derive from classes other than `System.Object`? (It goes without saying that `System.Object` will always be at the top of your class hierarchy in .NET)

Comment: I read that here: http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository
Under summary, it says: "The objects they create a free of base classes and exist on their own, as plain-old CLR objects (also known as POCOs)."

Comment: I believe the 'a' is supposed to be 'are'.

Answer (score 1):

When the word POCO is used, it's often to express the opposite of when you must inherit of a base class to use a frameork like some ORM tools requires:

MyClass : PersistableEntity (here PersistableEntity is a class to manage *technical* persistence in a ActiveRecord framework)

So you can't express inheritance in your class since you can only inherit from one class. If so you can use aggregation instead of inheritance.

So in your example, your class is POCO :)

Answer (score 0):

While you can use inheritance, I'm not sure data of type Latitude, and Longitude are allowed in plain old CLR/C# objects.